# Test Password with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test a passwprd which must have at least 6 characters and 1 number in it. What regex string I can use with JS to get this done?

UPDATED
I forgot to write it must have at least 6 alpha characters and 1 numeric character but it should also allow special characters or any other character. Can you please modify your answers? I greatly appreciated your responses

Comment: sounds like homework to me....

Comment: A good resource to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does smell a little like a homework question, but oh well.  You can actually accomplish this concisely using a single regular expression and the "look ahead" feature.

```
/(?=.{6}).*\d.*/.test("helelo1")
```

The first bit in the brackets says "peek ahead to see if there's 6 characters".  Following this we check for any number of characters, followed by a number, followed by any number of characters.

It is even possible to accomplish your goal in a single regex without having the faculty of look ahead...  It's just a little hard to look at the solution and not wince:

```
new RegExp("[0-9].....|" +
           ".[0-9]....|" +
           "..[0-9]...|" +
           "...[0-9]..|" +
           "....[0-9].|" +
           ".....[0-9]").test("password1")
```

Comment: +1 for your second regex being both really clever and awful at the same time. I'd have written the first one as `/(?=.*\d).{6,}/`, but it's tomayto/tomahto.

Comment: The 2nd regex won't work.  The requirements say "at least 6 characters", so you'd technically need an infinite number of those lines.

Comment: Actually, @cwolves, it will work.  You'd only need an infinite number of lines if you started your regex with ^ and ended it with $.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
password.match(/(?=.*\d).{6}/);
```

More info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Comment: @cwolves - On closer inspection, you're right. That would only have been true if it were `/^(?=.*\d).{6}$/`, which means this is actually pretty clever, now that I think about it. +1.

Comment: Good point.  This expression is best for finding *if* the strings matches, but not for matching the whole password.

Comment: FYI, the regex is actually faster this was as the engine can quit and say "true" as soon as it hits 6-characters.  The only downside is that this allows _anything_, even whitespace, tabs, nul characters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is best done with a combination of string functions and regex:

```
if( myPass.match(/[a-zA-Z]/).length >= 6 && myPass.match(/\d/g).length ) {
    // Good passwords are good!
}
```

EDIT: Updated to include the new stipulations. Special characters are allowed, but not required.

Comment: I agree, I am not sure you can do this with a straight regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/.{6,}/.test(password) && /\d/.test(password)) {
    // success
} else {
    // fail
}
```

Comment: Won't that allow special characters?

Comment: Yep.  Spec never said otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?=[\w\d]{6,}$)(?=.*\d)/.test(password)
```

- requires 6 or more characters (letters, numbers or _)
- requires at least one digit
- won't allow any special characters

Comment: Why shouldn't special characters be allowed?

Comment: @Justin - Just saying that this won't allow them.  You simply adjust the `[\w\d]` to allow whatever you want.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. BTW, the `[\w\d]` is actually redundant; `\w` includes digits. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand

Answer (score 0):

This is a js to check password,

it checks min 7 chars, contains 1 Upper case and 1 digit and 1 special character and must not contain a space, hope it will help you.

```
 pwLength = this.value.length;

if (pwLength > 7 && pwLength < 21) {
        charLengthIcon.removeClass("fail").addClass("pass");
}
else charLengthIcon.removeClass("pass").addClass("fail");

if (this.value.match(/[A-Z]/g)) {
    capLetterIcon.removeClass("fail").addClass("pass");
}
else capLetterIcon.removeClass("pass").addClass("fail");

if (this.value.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
    numberIcon.removeClass("fail").addClass("pass");
}
else numberIcon.removeClass("pass").addClass("fail");

if (this.value.match(/[@#$%!$&~*^(){}?><.,;:"'-+=|]/g)) {
    splcharIcon.removeClass("fail").addClass("pass");
}
else splcharIcon.removeClass("pass").addClass("fail");

if (this.value.match(/[\s/]/g)) {
    whiteSpce.removeClass("pass").addClass("fail");
}
else whiteSpce.removeClass("fail").addClass("pass");


confirmPW();
```

});