# Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making form and there is only one more thing which I cant figure it out :(

I need regular expression for password which  must be at least 7 characters long. There can be small and big letters and **must contain at least one number**.

I tried

```
[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]){7}$
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300009/test-password-with-regex) looks pretty close to what you seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookahead:

```
^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{7,}$
```

---

`(?=.*\d)` is a *lookahead* which checks for a digit in the string. Basically, `.*` matches the whole string and then backtracks 1 by 1 to match a digit. If it matches a digit, the regex engine comes back to its position before match. So, it just **checks** for a pattern.

`{7,}` is a quantifier which matches previous pattern 7 to many times

`^` is the beginning of a string

Comment: I like this solution... simple and elegant.

Comment: @Anirudh
Thank you very much, this looks so simple :)